# viewWillAppear not called when going back on a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, viewwillappear

I have some code I call that changes the language in the viewWillAppear section of a viewcontroller inside a navigation controller.  [image]

When I hit the back button the language change doesn't take place even though I have code for it to in the viewWillAppear.  The only time it switches is when I hit back all the way to the original screen and then start moving forward it changes.  Is there any way to have the function in the viewWillAppear work?

Here is my code, I'm using a language changing pod:

```
  //MARK: Language change

  //used to change language text for imediate screens
  func setText(){
    locationsLabel.text = "Locations".localized()
    languageLabel.text = "Languages".localized()
    termsOfUseLabel.text = "Terms of Use".localized()
    privacyPolicyLabel.text = "Privacy Policy".localized()
    pushNotificationsLabel.text = "Push Notifications".localized()
    contactUsLabel.text = "Contact Us".localized()
  }


  // Changes text to current language
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setText", name: LCLLanguageChangeNotification, object: nil)
  }

  // Remove the LCLLanguageChangeNotification on viewWillDisappear
  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `viewWillAppear()`?

Comment: @LukeVanIn I updated the question with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewWillAppear` method is only adding a notification observer. The observer is removed in `viewWillDisappear`. This means that `setText` will only be called if the `LCLLanguageChangeNotification` notification is sent *while the view is visible*.

The update stops as soon as the view goes off-screen due to the navigation behaviour.

To ensure that the text is updated, you also need to call `setText` inside `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setText()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setText", name: LCLLanguageChangeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: @ Luke Van In That did it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Implement navigationcontroller delegate methods

```
navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with those methods, how would you implement them?

Answer (score 0):

I have created this little class that solves this problem. 
Just set it as a delegate of your navigation controller, and implement simple one or two methods in your view controller - that will get called when the view is about to be shown or has been shown via NavigationController

[Here's the GIST showing the code](https://gist.github.com/greggjaskiewicz/70f4a37cf6abc51423c9ecbb0033d6c7)